# Why the password buffer comes always first in the stack?

Tags: c, memory, gdb, stack, buffer

I must declare these 2:

```
int auth_flag = 0;
char password_buffer[16];
```

No matter the order I declare them the password buffer **always comes first in the stack**, allowing buffer overflow to `auth_flag`

Why is that happening?

[(screenshot)GDB - password buffer declared first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzW6S.png)

[(screenshot)GDB - password buffer declared second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmqPG.png)

Comment: The compiler can choose where to place the variables in the stack (if at all) and it does not have to correlate with the order of the original source code. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is desired that auth_flag comes before password_buffer (in the stack) in order to avoid buffer overflow from password_buffer to auth_flag.

Comment: @UselessAf If you have a buffer overflow, anything could happen, your code is broken. The order of the variables should *never* be necessary, because everything might be broken as soon as you have an overflow, not just a specific variable. Write code that doesn't let you overflow the buffer.

Comment: @UselessAf What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was following the example of a book, in which what I wanted to do here worked for them. I'm trying to place auth_flag before password_buffer in the stack.  This we can't use password_buffer to achieve overflow and sneak data in auth_flag.

Comment: But then the buffer overflow would overwrite something else and lead to some other undesirable behaviour. Your whole premise of using ordering to mitigate buffer overflows is totally flawed and not worth persuing. The right way is to prevent buffer overflows in the first place.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I agree with you. Still I wonder how compiler comes to the decision... cheers

Comment: Are you sure there is not a typo in your code?  (  `auth_flag` --- `aauth_flag` )  This could be just one more example of why posting a [mcve] is a good idea.

Comment: I'm sure. The code is as shown in the screenshots

Comment: That is my point.  There is _"No symbol  `aauth_flag` in current context"_.  This is flagged in the screen shot.  See post below.

Comment: The question of how compiler places symbols in stack is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: @kaylum: Re “The right way is to prevent buffer overflows in the first place”: Humans have proven themselves unable to achieve that with 100% success, so seeking additional mitigations has value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sure, but this isn't a mitigation at all. Changing the order would just mean sometbing else (such as the return address or an even more important variable) would get overwritten instead. There are easier and more effective migitation strategies and those should be used instead.

Comment: If you want them in a specific order, you can place them both in a `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

If a compiler merely put objects on the stack in the order they were declared, it would waste space. For example, in a typical C implementation, given `char a; int b; char c; double d;`, the `a` would require one byte, then three bytes would have to be wasted to get to the four-byte alignment that `int` requires, then `b` takes four bytes and `c` takes one, and then seven bytes would be wasted to get to the eight-byte alignment that `double` requires.

To optimize space, a compiler groups objects based on their alignment requirements. Typically, the compiler author(s) write some algorithm that puts all the eight-byte-alighment objects together, then all the four-byte-alignment objects, then all the two-byte-alignment objects, then all the one-byte-alignment objects (and more before those if there are objects with stricter requirements). This algorithm might assign the space from low addresses to high addresses; it really does not matter, as long as it is orderly. But, whatever order the author(s) choose, that is the order that the compiler will use, regardless of declaration order.

There can be other factors too. As a compiler is reading declarations, it may record information about the declarations in an internal database. When it is time to assign space for objects defined by the declarations, it may process the identifiers from the database in a different order than they were read. For example, after ordering them by the alignment requirements as noted above, it might process them in alphabetical order or in the order that a hash function happened to store them in a table or in an order that results from traversing a tree by in-order or pre-order algorithms.